# how do I correlate time in mysql logs?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I can't seem to make sense of how to correlate time in the mariadb logs:

```
151004 15:34:36 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
151004 15:34:36 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
151004 15:34:36 [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event
151004 15:34:36 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mariadb-bin.000078', position 376
151004 15:36:47 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mariadb-bin.000078' at position 376, relay log './db4-relay-bin.000042' position: 537
151004 15:36:47 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'jf_slave@db2.example.com:3306',replication started in log 'mariadb-bin.000078' at position 376
151007  4:24:12 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
151007  4:24:12 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
151007  4:24:12 [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event
151007  4:24:12 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mariadb-bin.000078', position 376
151007  4:28:20 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mariadb-bin.000078' at position 376, relay log './db4-relay-bin.000043' position: 537
151007  4:28:20 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'jf_slave@db2.example.com:3306',replication started in log 'mariadb-bin.000078' at position 376
```

Can someone tell me from this example how to determine what time / date someting happened? Or am I correct in my assumption that mysql/mariadb doesn't represent dates, just times.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. That was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 151007  4:24:12 = 2015-10-07 04:24:12
>
> 151004 15:36:47 = 2015-10-04 15:36:47

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks! :)